# Relocation error when using gdb

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-creator, gdbserver

I'm experiencing a strange behavior that I need help resolving. We develop an Qt 5.8 application using Qt Creator for our i.MX6 board.
The application runs correctly in debug mode when it is started directly (or via gdb) on the target via a shell using the following argument:

```
-qmljsdebugger=port:10001,services:DebugMessages,QmlDebugger,V8Debugger,QmlInspector
```

However, whenever it is launched with remote gdb from host it prints out a relocation error. This behavior started to appear 
recently when more signals/properties were added to a model (which in no different to the existing models).

The following is printed in Qt Creator:

```
Debugging starts
Listening on port 10000
Remote debugging from host 192.168.213.11
Process /opt/app/bin/app created; pid = 4923
/opt/app/bin/app: relocation error: /opt/app/bin/app: symbol _ZTVN10__cxxabiv120__si_class���e_infoE, version CXXABI_1.3 not defined in file libstdc++.so.6 with link time reference
```

If the following lines (+ one emit) are removed from the code it starts up correctly:

```
Q_PROPERTY(bool deleted READ getDeleted WRITE setDeleted NOTIFY deletedChanged)
Q_SIGNAL void deletedChanged();
```

I have also noticed that if additional signals are added I get different error messages, for example if 3 new unused signals are added (it seems that it does not matter to what model the signals are added) I get

```
/opt/app/bin/app: relocation error: /opt/app/bin/app: symbol ���St9exception, version GLIBCXX_3.4 not defined in file libstdc++.so.6 with link time reference
```

The project has about 25 models with about 100 properties in total.

Any ideas where to go from here?

EDIT: The libraries and applications on target are prelinked once at fresh startup. I noticed that it works correctly if the application to debug is prelinked before gdb-debugging starts. Not sure I understand why.

Comment: I'm not familiar with QtCreator, but my first thoughts: 1) your QtCreator uses different glibc than your board, 2) QtCreator deploys its glibc during debugging session and because of that your app works